# Code to load TIFF image on openlayer.layer.wms using MapServer MS4W

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, mapserver

Where did I get mess up?

Here is my code inside the mapfile.map

```
LAYER 
    NAME "layername"
    STATUS OFF
    TYPE RASTER
    DATA "data/sample.tif"
END
```

The code inside explorer.js from where I declare the openlayers.layer.wms

```
    var showlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "my Layer Title", 
         my_url, 
        {
            layers: 'layername',
            'format':'image/tiff'

        },{
            singleTile: false,
            maxExtent: my_MapExtent,
            isBaseLayer: false

   })

   map.addLayer(showlayer);
```

When I open it in the browser here the error show's:

`msWMSLoadGetMapParams(): WMS server error. Invalid layer(s)`

any help or suggestion for this one?

Comment: Try first what happens with STATUS ON.

Comment: @user30184 i already turn it on and off and still the same error message.

Comment: Try then to remove quotes around parameter `format`. See how `transparent` is used in http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/WMS-js.html. But you should really use Firebug etc. so you can see what requests your application is sending.

Comment: @user30184 i deed remove it like format: 'image/tiff' but still no hope.

Comment: There is always hope. People do use MapServer with OpenLayers. Don't guess, find the actual GetMap that is generated. You will see what is wrong and then will know where to fix.

Comment: @user30184 here's the code of the variable my_url var my_url =  "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?MS_MAPFILE=c:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/mymap/_mapfile/mapfile.map&";

Comment: I think it should not be MS_MAPFILE but just `?map=`but the error message does suggest that MS_MAPFILE was accepted too. BTW. you should not really put mapfiles into htdocs where users from the web can see them. What is interesting is the GetMap request that is sent to that URL `&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=...`

Comment: @user30184 thank you so much for your great words 'There is always hope' and i made it view my .tiff file but only on safari. what i deed is i remove MS_MAPFILE and magic done.